# Adding a title to TreePlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is a basic question I am sure, but cannot seem to find the answer in the
documentation.
Does anyone know how to add a title to a TreePlot?

Comment: PlotLabel -> "title"?

Answer (score 3):

All plotting functions (i.e. functions that return `Graphics`) and all functions that create `Graph` objects take the [`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html) option.

Use

```
TreePlot[..., PlotLabel -> "My Tree!"]
```

It might be useful to mention that `Show` will convert `Graph` objects to `Graphics` objects, in case you need to use options that are *only* available for `Graphics`, but not `Graph`.

Finally, you can use [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to label anything in Mathematica, whether it's graphics, a graph, a formula, or anything else.

Comment: The `Show` comment is good to know indeed.